# whereNotIn condition in a collection

Tags: laravel

I try to display all the structures id but without the connected one

```
 $structures = Structure::whereNotIn('id' , Auth::user()->structure->id)->pluck('id');
```

But it's doesn't work , someone know the right query to achieve that ?

Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't use `whereNotIn()` here. Use `where()` instead:

```
$structures = Structure::where('id', '<>', Auth::user()->structure->id)->pluck('id');
```